# Using LTSpice to find the gain of NPN-PMOS folded cascode

Tags: ltspice, npn, gain, output, pmos

I am trying to use LTSpice to find the gain of NPN-PMOS folded cascode.
Below is the question prompt:

[image]

In the problem, the parameter specifications are as follows:
\begin{equation}
\beta =100,\:V_A=5V\:,\:I=0.1mA,\:V_{ov}=0.2V
\end{equation}
Now assuming some parameter sources like VCC=5V and vtp = -0.5V, we get VG = 4.3V. Using the voltage division properties for biasing by choosing some resistor values, the calculations result in the following voltage dividers for NPN and PMOS. Also, Vb for the NPN is 0.7V since it is a common source.

[image]

Now, I had to play with the circuit for quite sometime and the above seems to be the best so far. However, It is not correct. My gain is supposed to be
 Av=-10K V/V, so if am putting vi=0.005V, I should get vo=50V with a 180 degrees phase shift. Unfortunatley, I am not getting the required output. My output is not even oscillatory, it is a constant voltage of about 5V like below:

[image]

Can somebody please tell me what am doing wrong or how to properly build the circuit in LTSpice to get the required output?? thank you in advance.

Comment: Might help if you connect the two branches together, rather than have this PMOS dangling unrelated off the VCC. :-P

Comment: I did, when I implemented my circuit just like the drawing in the problem, LTspice would just freeze and stop working when I simulate. It is like going through endless iterations

Comment: LTSpice can freeze up yes, there's fixes for that. The question you're asking here, with that circuit is literally: "I have an output that's biased by DC sources, with no connection to any signal. Why doesn't my signal come out at all?" Can you possibly see the problem there?

Comment: Did I understand correctly: you expect 50V output from a 5V supply?

Comment: @a concerned citizen, the question is about getting a 50V sinusoidal output from a 0.005V sinusoidal input! NOT a 5V DC supply. The theoretical gain of this circuit is 10K V/V

Comment: @Raykh Your BJT collector is ***isolated*** from your FET by the infinite impedance of a current source (I1) that you decided to just plop in there because that's what you think the current should have divided out to be. Do you NOT see why this is a huge problem? I don't care about your earlier problems (simulation slowness, or *anything else*.) There is a huge problem ***here***.

Comment: @jonk, it would be great if you could clearly clarify, and provide a helpful answer. since am beginner with LTspice and have been trying too many things with no hope

Comment: @Raykh But this isn't an LTspice problem. This is a user problem. All Spice simulators would fail to do what you want, fed this schematic. Also, why do you think there is a lambda parameter for an NPN?

Comment: @jonk, If I would assume you are in expert with LTSpice , Lambda is used to account for ro. Since VA=1/lambda

Comment: @Raykh I'm not an expert with LTspice. Never claimed to be. I use it, that's all. I'd like you to call up the help for LTspice and find the location on the page describing parameters it accepts there (Gummel Poon, modified, or VBIC, either) that uses that particular name. I am unable to find it, myself. And I know that LTspice ignores what it cannot understand.

Comment: @Raykh Also, do you actually intend VA=5 (has to be an IC BJT, if so.)

Comment: (1) Put a series capacitor and a high (Meg) load resistor to ground from there, to your PMOS output. (2) Get rid of the 5V supply rail. (3) Get rid of the 100uA current source in the BJT collector. (4) Connect PMOS source to BJT collector and place your 200uA current source there, too (other end connected to ground is fine.) (5) Bias the PMOS correctly -- gate voltage is way off. (6) Use a 1uA source to the BJT base and dump R3 and R4, for now. (7) LTspice wants VDMOS, not PMOS. Inside the parens, you add "pchan" to the model. (8) I get gain of 400 with VA=5. Did you account for VA?

Comment: @Jonk, again!! The gain should be around 10K V/V that is what I stated in the question

Comment: @Raykh I know what you wrote. But I don't see it with VA=5. In any case, you haven't written anything at all about your analysis here. So I can't comment. And therefore there is no point in trying to point out how to use LTspice here, either. I would not know where to start and end. I did find LTspice quite capable of running something similar, though. Not slow. No problems. It just runs and produces reasonable results so far as my own ignorance allows.

Comment: @Jonk, OK!! The question is clearly stated and I provided all the necessary information. The goal is to use LTSpice results to match hand calculations which I don't need to show and confident they are correct. If you have a helpful answer please post it. Otherwise, refrain from making a long thread  by making "SMART" comments. Provided you couldn't reach the correct solution despite your "SMART" comments, please give the chance for other people to comment so this post can helpful in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @Raykh I said I'm ignorant and no expert on LTspice. No idea where you are coming from since I'm actually sincerely trying to see if there is some way I may be able to help. I'll assume it's not wanted and will step aside and allow someone else the privilege. But I will leave you with the fact that you have little place to speak, given the LTspice schematic you posted. It's not even close.

Comment: @Raykh Congratulations, your creed that you're doing everything right made you blind towards jonk's help, or anyone else's. 1) Trace the path of the signal from input to output, see what's wrong. 2) If the input is 5mV and the gain 10k, then the output should be 50V, which is 10x above the supply you're using. 3) You should generally start from the logic of: "if I am asking, I am the one who should listen in order to reason", but this is off-topic on ee.se, so feel free to ignore it (which I am sure you will).

Comment: @ a concerned citizen, I post the question here because am willing to learn and benefit from this divers and experienced community. Your attitude and Jonk's attitude clearly shows that you are here to post "SMART" comments and making me feel dumb. I think you have a big misunderstanding for the meaning of help. Helping people implies providing answers that spot the error and being NICE about it NOT being rude and making others feel stupid. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @Raykh No, you are the one who wants to play smart by dismissing helpful comments and downplaying all the other's efforts, because you're so sure you are not wrong (sign of narcissism). Everybody told or hinted at you *very nicely* that you are making mistakes, and to all you replied "no, I am not". For this, and for your slimey attitude (blame LTspice, when told that's not to blame, blame something else), you get -1 from me, and I don't have itchy fingers.

Comment: @ a concerned citizen, I never dismissed helpful comments and DO NOT claim things I never said. I clearly posted in the question that I need somebody TO "clearly tell what am doing wrong or how to build the circuit properly." I NEVER said others were wrong and I was right. This clearly shows that you are NOT here for help, but just to humiliate others. Please Stop blaming others for not being able to FIX the problem in hand, this is not how professional engineers work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit has nothing to do with folded cascode. It looks like to me that you completely do not understand how folded cascode amplifier work. Or even how amplifier work.

Can you show me the signal path for a signal in your simulation?

Also, you have some problems with the basics of electronics and how it relates to a real world. It is impossible to get a gain of 10kV/V in this circuit in real-life (50V at the output from 5V supply?).

The corrected circuit may look like this: 
[image]

And the small signal parameters:

\$g_{m1} \approx \frac{100\mu\textrm{A}}{25\textrm{mV}} \approx 4\textrm{mS} \$

\$r_{o1} \approx \frac{5\textrm{V}}{0.1\textrm{mA}} = 50\textrm{k}\Omega\$

To found the MOSFET transconductance we need to solve for Vgs:

$$I_D = \frac{K_P}{2}(V_{GS} - V_T)^2 \cdot (1 + \lambda \cdot 2V_{GS}) $$

2Vgs because I use R1 = R2 hence Vds = 2Vgs

And the solution for this for \$I_D = 100\mu\textrm{A}\$ and \$KP=5\textrm{m}\$ is \$V_{GS} = 0.6774\textrm{V}\$

Now I can find the MOSFET transconductance as:

\$g_{m2} = \frac{2I_D}{V_{GS} - V_T} \approx 1.3\textrm{mS}\$

And

\$r_{o2} = \frac{V_A + V_{DS}}{I_D} \approx 63.5\textrm{k}\Omega\$

And to find the theoretical voltage gain it is better to proform AC-sweep analysis in LTpsice. Set AC input source to 1V and plot Vout in linear scale.
Because in AC analysis power supply limitation don't exist.

[image]

Also, for a BJT to model the Early effect we are using VA parameter not lambda. Lambda is reserved for MOSFET lambda = 1/VA.

Comment: Well you did achieve a gain of about 13K V/V, which is kinda close to 10K V/V. Secondly, I am a beginner in LTSpice and the problem I posted is for an IC circuit for which the book does not provide any biasing arrangements

Comment: But you must understand that the problem is not in LTpice. Your circuit is wrong. One question: Can you explain to me "how" Vi source influence the MOSFET circuit? Which current (in mosfet) can Vi source modulated in the rhythm of an input signal?

Comment: Yeah, I know my circuit is wrong and I have been trying too many things with no hope. That is why I posted the question here to get the help

Comment: @G36 Don't bother, he says LTspice is to blame, when pushed to corner and shown that LTspice is not to blame, he will blame something else, and so on, all the while pointing fingers at those that try to help by saying they are the ones not helping.

Comment: @G36 Thank you very much for taking the time to provide this helpful answer. Now I can spot my error and fix my mistake. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @G36, just wanna make a quick comment. Your biasing arrangement is really clever for the NPN. A couple questions for clarification I wanna ask. So, in the problem statement; IC would be 100uA, how come we are using 100.1uA? for the PMOS biasing: is there a reason for choosing 100Meg or would a 10Meg be just as fine?? Thank you very much

Comment: You could use 100uA if you want. But I just want to compensate the R1, R2 current, and I want PMOS current to be100uA. This is why I set 200.1uA. Because these resistors current must come from this current source (200.1uA). As for the resistor values, the large the better because these resistors will affect the AC gain also.